# Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am getting the above error on the following line of code

DocsPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\" & "Documents\" & [Invoice] & ".csv"

Invoice is defined earlier as String

The purpose of the code it to define a filename that will change for each new invoice that the code will create, it will be used to save the invoice and later email the invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to think that the DocsPath name is defined as a function, have you tried declaring a different name as a String variable?

Try:

```
Dim strDocPath as String
strDocPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\" & [Invoice] & ".csv"
```